# Drawing a graph representing traffic flow with computer software

Tags: graph-theory

Hello I'm trying to draw a graph representing traffic flow in a city or local neighborhood with vertices that will represent points of interest to a person and edges which will represent various different routes either local or highway. The problem is that I do not know of any user friendly computer software which can assist me in attempting to construct such a graph. Any suggestions of such computer software that can draw out a traffic flow graph like the one I described will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: A useful distinction to keep in mind is whether "traffic" flows in one direction or in both directions along an edge.  The choice of software to draw such graphs is peripheral to this SE Community, if not simply off-topic.  However a search engine might help locate related queries at Software Recommendations SE.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source graph-based database system called Neo4j you may want to check out. It may be overkill depending on your needs, but there's no harm in looking at its features. Instead of SQL, where data is stored in rows and columns, in Neo4j data is stored in nodes (people in this city) and edges (traffic along this highway). You can write queries in its programming language to search or manipulate the data.

The default program that is used to access the databases has a GUI that allows you to manually create nodes, draw links between them, and edit the data containing them.

https://neo4j.com/

Comment: "Hello I'm trying to *draw* a graph..."  (my emphasis)  Nothing in your response appears to connect with the basic request of "[d]rawing a graph".